# Error trying to edit a script src attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

[I'm trying to follow this Google Maps example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple), but instead of hardcoding my API KEY, I'm trying to fetch it from an API I created.
So, I created this HTML file. The KEY is properly fetched, but when I'm trying to set the script's `src` attribute on runtime (so I can add my own key to the URI), it's not getting added at all.

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple markers example</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
    </script>

    <script async defer>
      $.get( "maps_api_key", function( data ) {
        const API_KEY = String(data)
        console.log("API_KEY: " + API_KEY)
        var uri = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + API_KEY + "&callback=initMap"
        console.log("URI is: " + uri)
        $("#maps_fetcher").attr("src", uri)
      });
    </script>

    <script id="maps_fetcher" async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
      console.log("Map fetcher")      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The line at `console.log("Map fetcher")` is never being printed either.
For what it's worth, I'm serving the HTML through Node and Express.

Any ideas on what could be happening here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: *`console.log("Map fetcher")`* isn't working because a `<script>` element should have either a `src` or inline content but not both. The `maps_fetcher` is probably loading with the hardcoded URL because your other script doesn't change it until after the Ajax response comes back. Can you remove the entire `maps_fetcher` script and append it programmatically from your Ajax response handler? (Incidentally, you know that passing the API_KEY around this way doesn't actually stop an end user from finding out what it is?)

Comment: Good catch, thanks. I deleted it and I'm getting this on console:
1. `Map fetcher`  
2. `markers.html:44 API_KEY: ...`  
3. `markers.html:46 URI is: ...`  
so the last script in file is getting evaluated too early. Shouldn't `async defer` scripts be executed in order?

Comment: Even if the two scripts are executed in order, the first one kicks off an asynchronous Ajax request, that is, it doesn't wait for the response. The Ajax callback runs *later*, after the response is received.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nnnnnn you're comments have been really helpful. If you want to create an answer with them, I'll approve it

Comment: By the way: I didn't really mind about whether the API can be seen, I just didn't want to add it in a VCS-visible file